What is the opposite of "He's full of life"?
I want to say that I'm often drowsy in the morning and I don't want to do anything. I think this state is opposite to being "full of life".
But what is the antonym of it?

There's nothing wrong with the obvious - just say you feel really lifeless in the morning.

Informally, you could say:

I'm not a morning person.

... and everyone would know what you mean!

'Drowsy' tends to describe the state of wanting or needing to fall asleep. That isn't quite the right word for how you might feel waking up after too little sleep. The feeling of still being tired immediately after sleep is usually called grogginess, or feeling 'groggy'

I feel groggy in the morning if I don't get enough sleep.

You might also consider:

Lethargic (not having enough energy)
Dazed (a state of mild confusion, not having fully woken up yet)

We also say things like "I'm still half asleep", "I've not fully woken up yet" and "I'm still coming around" when we feel like we are tired in the morning. Some of these are somewhat hyperbolic.

A good phrase I can think is
drained up
Other antonyms for 'full of life' are
unenergetic, unenthusiastic, half-hearted, dreamy, lackadaisical, languid, languorous. lacking spirit or liveliness. listless. lacking zest or vivacity

And let’s not forget indolent.
